# Solve or express equation with respect to another variable

Tags: equation-solving

I have code which I think is all right. I just need help with the last part, expressing the last equation `eq` with respect to `u/ef`

Here's what my textbook says on how to do last equation.

[image]

I already made substitution for `g0`, so I got last equation similar to Eq(7.65) in the book, following the discussion starting with "Cancelling the N's ..." to express this with respect to `u/ef`.

Here is my code:

```
nfd[e_, t_] := 1/(Exp[(e - u)/(k*t)] + 1);

n1[e_, t_] := Integrate[g[e]*nfd[e], {e, 0, Infinity}];

d = -D[nfd[e, t], e]; 
d1 = d /. e - u -> x*k*t;

s1 = Normal[Series[e^(3/2), {e, u, 5}]]; 
s2 = s1 /. e - u -> k*t*x;

n13[t_] := 
  (2/3)*g0*Integrate[k*t*s2*d1, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] /. Rule -> Equal;

eq[t_] := n13[t] /. {g0 -> (3 n)/(2 *ef^(3/2))} // Expand;


simp = Expand[Refine[eq[t] == n, Assumptions -> {n == 1}]]
```

Comment: Apologies if this seems pedantic, but I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you just asking how to get from 7.65 to 7.66? From 7.65 the author just sets mu to epsilon in the second term, giving epsilon^2 in the denominator, then subtracts all the correction terms from 1 on the LHS and takes the 2/3 root to isolate mu/epsilon. I don't think you can do this automatically in Mathematica, it requires some realization on your part that mu~epsilon and the correction is small.

Answer (score -1):

```
Simplify[eq /. u -> ef x, ef > 0] // Expand

(*  (7 k^4 n \[Pi]^4 t^4)/(640 ef^4 x^(5/2)) + (k^2 n \[Pi]^2 t^2)/(
  8 ef^2 Sqrt[x]) + n x^(3/2) == n  *)
```

??

Comment: no sorry. it should be like last equation in the book EQ(7.66)